# Fork program gives <defunct> processes after some time

Tags: c++, fork

I am developing a program that is doing various tasks using `fork()`. I am starting the program, everything works fine. I observed that after some time (1 day) i get flooded with `<defunct>` processes, over 600 700 ... where max forks is setted to 500. This is the code :

```
int numforks = 0;
int maxf = 100;

// READ FROM FILE ...
while (fgets(nutt,2048,fp))
{
    fflush(stdout);
    if (!(fork()))
    {
        some_time_intensive_function();
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        numforks++;

        if (numforks >= maxf)
        {
            wait(NULL);
            numforks--;
        }
    }   
}

// DON'T EXIT PROGRAM TILL ALL FORKS ARE FINISHED
while(numforks>0)
{
    wait(NULL);
    numforks--;
}

// CLOSE READ FILE ...
```

This programs keeps all the time 500 forks oped like a thread pool.

I don't really understand what `<defunct>` processes are, but i heard that they aren't errors in the child processes like `SEG FAULT` occurring, but rather parent process is not waiting correctly.

I want to get read of `<defunct>`s, any ideas to solve this?

I repeat, this happens after some time 1-2 days.

Thank you.

Comment: Missing `Linux` tag (or `POSIX` one)

Comment: Wait, won't your child processes also fork once `some_time_intensive_function` finishes and they loop back around to the "while fgets" part? It looks like you may have written a very slow fork bomb.

Comment: i don't quite understand this slow fork bomb, the program reads a big text file then forks processes to do it faster, not one by one

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch if I'd done that, i would got -1 ...

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two problems:

Firstly `wait` can return for reasons other than a child process has terminated (and if it does, it will leave a defunct process).  I think you need to pass in a non-null pointer, and inspect the returned wait status.  Only decrement numforks if appropriate.

Secondly`numforks` doesn't (effectively) limit the total number of child processes.  If the parent process launches two processes, they will each go on to inherit `numforks` of 0 and 1.  Then each of those child processes will launch 500 and 499 more subprocesses.

I think you need `exit(0)` (or `break`) after your `time_consuming_process()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I forgot when i copied the text, there is a `exit(0);` there, look on update. `wait can return for reasons other than a child process has terminated` - > i really did not know that, really ... and about `numforks` if i stay with `ps aux | grep executable` it is doing fine ...

Comment: If there is an `exit(0)`, then `numforks` will work.  However, it is still the case that each time you return from `wait` early, you will leak a child process - and the number of these can grow without limit.

Comment: i just started the exe with 500 forks, and now shows 4-5 `<defunct>` then disspears , and after some times i get floaded with 300 400 constant different `<defunct>` ... maybe i should print what `wait()` returns, what is should return if everything is ok?

Comment: hmm, i should put a print on what `wait()` retunrs, what is the normal value for success of `wait()` ?  Really, what had you said with `can return for reasons other than a child process has terminated` might be the solution, maybe sometimes the child gets an error and messes up the fork mechanism ...

Comment: The link is to the documentation for all the wait functions.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(I assume you are running on Linux, or some other POSIX system like MacOSX)</sup>

Beware of  [orphan processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process).

Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) which has several chapters related to your issue.

You'll better *keep* the result of `fork` (in some `pid_t` variable or field), and handle all three cases (>0: `fork` was successful; ==0, in child process, <0: `fork` failed!). And you should probably call [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) appropriately. In the child process it is reasonable to call [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) (or [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)...)

Perhaps you should handle `SIGCHLD` signal. Read *carefully* [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

<sup>(you don't show enough of your program, and an entire book is needed to explain all that)</sup>

As a rule of thumb you don't want to have *many* runnable processes. On a typical laptop or desktop computer, you should not have more than a *dozen* of *runnable* processes. Use [top(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) or [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) to list your processes (and notably to understand how many processes you have). Perhaps use (at least during debugging) bash `ulimit` [builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) (it calls [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) from inside your shell)  in your terminal e.g. as `ulimit -u 50` to limit the number of processes (to 50).

If coding in genuine C++11, you should consider using frameworks like [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) (both provide support for processes).

You should care about [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (perhaps with [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s or [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)-s and some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), see [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) ...) and [synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29) issues. Perhaps look into [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) or [0mq](http://zeromq.org/).

<sup>(you probably need to read a lot more)</sup>

Perhaps [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) might be helpful to debug your issues.

Don't forget to check *every* [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). See [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) & [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answers, really helpfully. So `wait(NULL);` might not be the best idea, i should use `pid_t pid = fork()` , `waitpid` , i have to rethink the forking mechanism. About Ot, POCO, pipe, socket ... i don't want to go that deep yet. I have 2 questions. 1 This problem is related to the fork mecanism, or childs get errors like seg fault? 2 And the second question, why is this happening after 2 days of perfect running? This is the problem that is troubling me, because it is not a bug that triggers right away, i have to wait 2 days to see if i solve it ...

Comment: You should avoid having many runnable processes. You can use `top` to see your processes.

Comment: Just use `ulimit` appropriately to lower your process limit, at least during the debugging phase.

Comment: i actually use `htop` and `watch -n 0.1 'ps aux | grep defunct | wc -l ; ps aux | grep defunct'`  ... how much to limit with `ulimit` ?

Comment: I have no idea. You need to experiment (various `ulimit` settings)

Comment: i should check both `fork()` and `wait()` returns if they are ok?

Comment: You should check *every* [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). See [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) & [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).